# Pentaho Data Integration setVariable not working

Tags: variables, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am on PDI 7.0 and have a "Modified Java Script Value" step inside a transformation as below:

```
var numberOfDays = 100;
Alert(numberOfDays);
setVariable("NUMBER_OF_DAYS", numberOfDays, "r");
Alert(getVariable("NUMBER_OF_DAYS", ""));
```

However, when I run the transformation, the first Alert correctly throws 100, but the next Alert is blank (meaning the variable is not set).

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a **rule of thumb**, you should **never set** a variable **and read** it within the **same transformation**.

See a warning that pops up in Spoon when setting up `Set Variables` step:

[image]

That said, what you could do, if you really insist on setting this via Java Script is the following design:

[image]

where

1) Set variable transformation is used to set the value:

```
var numberOfDays = 100;
Alert(numberOfDays);
setVariable("NUMBER_OF_DAYS", numberOfDays, "r");
```

2) Get variable transformatoin only reads it

```
Alert(getVariable("NUMBER_OF_DAYS", ""));
```

Both transformations use the same steps, but they have separate task.

Comment: If we right click on setVariable special function in spoon and click Sample, the sample they provide does setVariable and then alert... they should change this not to confuse newbies like me..

Comment: I have a Generate Rows step in next transformation where I want to use the variables set in my first transformation. I have NUMBER_OF_DAYS and START_DATE set in first step as above... I want to use NUMBER_OF_DAYS as Limit inside my Generate Rows step of next transformation, and START_DATE as value of one of the field inside Generate Rows step... I tried ${NUMBER_OF_DAYS} and ${START_DATE} but its not working.. am I missing something?

Comment: Does the KTR with the generate rows have a blank parameter created ? And also, you need to use the 'Copy previous result to parameter' + 'execute for every input row'. See if that works. I answered a similar question, there is a sample there you might be able to use and adapt. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387510/pentaho-kettle-get-the-file-names-dynamically/52387638#52387638)

Comment: @Nik questions you're raising are a different topic to be posted on StackOverflow with more details.