# Pentaho Kettle - Get the file names dynamically

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pdi, data-integration

I hope this message finds everyone well!

I'm stucked on a situation on Pentaho PDI Tool and I'm looking for an answer (or at least a light in the end of the cave) to solve it!

I have to import, every month, a bunch of xls's files of differents clients. Every file has a different name (witch is given aleatory) and this files are on a folder named with the name of the client. However, I use the same process for all clients and situations.

Is there a way to pass the name of the directory as a variable and change this variable on every process? How can I read this files on differents paths?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you're looking for requires a flow with variables as you stated. In a JOB you will start with a KTR with the client's name and their respective folder. In the same JOB you are going to pass these results and use them as variables, to another JOB if needed, or to a KTR, and you are going to use the options "Copy previous results to parameters" and "Execute for every input row" (Advanced Tab), and in the parameters tab you will name the variables and stream column name (where the data is coming from in the previous KTR, ie.: Clients name and directory).

If you have trouble with creating this flow i can spare some more time and share a sample if you need.

EDIT:
[Sample Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IcJ0_vaB_i0t6ee7T5bhl3DcmdBRIcEz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I really appreciated your answer, thank you so much! I'll try follow your tips and update my situation.

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you so much!

I have one more question: the folder named with the name of the client will be created in execution time. For example: today I got a new client named "Cris". One folder will be created with the name "Cris" and every excel file will be inside it. So, my workflow has to find this new folder and process it.

Is there a way to do it on Kettle (comparing folders or getting the name of the new folder on a file)?

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing before hand what the Client folder is going to be ? Maybe you can keep this data on a DB or even in a simple Excel File. Then you would replace the Data Grid step for it. Or even, if the clients name is always the same as the folder, then thats that, you can use the client name in the Get Files name step

Comment: That's a great tip, actually. Yes, I have a way of knowing what client will enter on my system. I'm thinking about create a table with two fields: parameter and path. On the first one, I'll write just "Directory" and, on the second, I'll write the entire path of the client's xls (C:/...Cris/). If I did it, it's just replace the Data Grid Step (Client_info.ktr) for that, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have an example of this in the sample directory which is shipped with your PDI distribution.

Your case is covered by the `samples/jobs/run_all`.